# How do you move the contents of an iframe's body to the body of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

UPDATE:

I was mislead, by some mistake I had made, into thinking that I could not both have a running script updating the screen AND an outstanding submit that would reload the page upon completion.

You can do this, and I have. The way that I did it was to place my updater on a startTimeout and let the submit continue.

```
    $('#JQF').on('submit', function(){
      start();
      return true;
    });
...
start: 
  function (xhr, s) {
    $(".appMainMsg").hide();
    bar = document.getElementById("ProgressBar");
    if (bar)
    {
      eta = document.getElementById("ProgressBarEta");
      startTime = new Date();
      infoUpdated = 0;
      infoRequested = 0;

      $(bar).empty().progressbar();
      setTimeout(requestInfo, 2);
    }
  },
...
```

ORIGINAL Question:

I have a page that posts a form with file uploads and targets the response to an hidden iframe. When the iframe finishes loading, it calls a function in the (main) page. If all looks good, I want to move the contents of the body that loaded into the iframe to the main page's body, else I will just leave things alone. I do have jquery loaded so I'd like to use that.

```
<body>
  <iframe name='ifr' id='ifr' style='display: none;'></iframe>
  <form target='ifr' method='post' action='mypage.php'>
  </form>
  <script>
  function finished()
  { if (iLikeIt) 
    { 
      //replace body contents with ifr.body.contents
      // keeping all event handlers attached
      // something like...

      WHAT DO I PUT HERE?
    }
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

The page loaded into the iframe, ends with:

```
<script>
  setTimeout(parent.finished, 1000); // some time for navel gazing
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use AJAX-loading the content? It's asynchronous so it will trigger the callback when the data sent back is ready. It indeed won't keep any bindings you have to re-invoke them.

Comment: Ajax is a better option, unless of course you have file inputs which you want to work in IE6.

Comment: "It indeed won't keep any bindings you have to re-invoke them" ... unless event handling was delegated to the `document` in the first place.

Comment: Yes, there are file uploads. Do I understand that I will have to reconnect the event handlers by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need iframe to do this. I recommend to submit your form by ajax.
Since you have jquery loaded, the easiest option for you is to use [jquery-form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

Here is a working example of what you are looking for:

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(function(){

        // instead of redirecting to upload.php, your form "#form"
        // will now be submitted by ajax and you'll get response
        // content in html parameter of success callback
        $('#form').ajaxForm({
            // you can handle "json" or "xml" content types too
            // @see http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#json
            dataType:  'text',
            success: function(html) {

                // in case you want to replace your document
                // content with the response content
                $(document.body).html(html);
            }
        });



        // This is how you "keep all event handlers attached", with
        // live method instead of bind.
        // So if you have #btn2 element in ajax response, and you replace
        // document content with this ajax response, jquery will auto-bind
        // 'click' event on new #btn2 element
        // Note that you can also use bind, but you'll have to "re-bind"
        // the event manualy (inside "success" callback in this case).
        $("#btn2").live("click", function(){alert("button 2 clicked")});

    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ajax form:</h1>
    <form id="form" action="upload.php" method="post"> 
        <input type="file" name="file" /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit File" /> 
    </form>

    <h1>keeping all event handlers attached exemple:</h1>
    <button id="btn2">click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php:**

```
<?php

    // here you handle your $_FILES, $_POST, $_GET ...


    // html response example:
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    echo '<h1>This is your ajax html response:</h1>';
    echo '<button id="btn1">click me</button>';
    var_dump($_FILES);
    echo '<h1>keeping all event handlers attached exemple:</h1>';
    echo '<button id="btn2">click me</button>';
    echo '<script>

            $(function(){

                // js event handler attached to #btn1
                $("#btn1").bind("click", function(){alert("button 1 clicked")});
            });

        </script>';
```

Comment: In fact I don't need ajax (in any of it's forms), I can just start of the screen modifier function on a setTimeout and let the form submit proceed.